# How to transform RGBI (4 band) to RGB (3 band)?

Tags: qgis, raster

I got 4 band RGBIs and I need to transform them to 3 band in order to be able to use them in Agisoft Metashape.
I didn't find a way to delete the 4th band (NIR), so I created 3 new images (each containing 1 band) by using the raster calculator. Afterwards I merged them. As result I got a image with 3 bands, but the first band always gets "gray" in brackets. And when I export them the outcome is a white picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Rearrange bands** tool (QGIS version 3.4 +) can delete the 4th band easily.

[image]

1. Go to the Processing Toolbox: `GDAL > Raster conversion` and start **Rearrange bands** tool.
2. Select your multiband (RGBI) raster as the Input layer.
3. Click on a small three-dots icon at the right of `Selected band(s)` option.
4. Select first three bands (Bands 1, 2, 3) and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>, then <kbd>Run</kbd> to start the process.