# Converting RGBA to RGB in QGIS - output file too large

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I have RGBA TIFF file 3.5gb and when I convert it to RGB it becomes 60gb(

I'm using [How to transform RGBI (4 band) to RGB (3 band)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337911/how-to-transform-rgbi-4-band-to-rgb-3-band) this method

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Uncompressed images are larger than compressed images https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329483/file-size-inflation-using-gdal.

Comment: Select  "High Compression" on the Profile drop down.